# Access property from webpack.config.js within a plugin?

Tags: webpack, webpack-plugin

Imagine having a webpack.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
...
  externals: ["dependency1"],
...
}
```

How can I access this information in my plugin, without passing this information directly in my Plugin Constructor? (I would prefer to have it at one place.)

Answer (score 3):

Try `compilation.options.externals`. Some information about the compilation object [here](https://webpack.js.org/api/compilation-object/) (nothing about the `options` property though).